# how to get 'MFC :: ON_CONTROL_RANGE' like behavior in Winforms using C#

Tags: c#, winforms, mfc, event-handling

In my Win forms app,
I have around 25 buttons, I want to call a same function on 'click' event of those button.

Is there anything Like MFC's, [ON_CONTROL_RANGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e3sz709f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
macro in C#.

```
ON_CONTROL_RANGE(BN_CLICKED, id1, id2, memberFun )
```

or i have to manually add event handlers for all the buttons.

Any help would be greatefull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make things slightly easier and (imho) more maintainable, you could take advantage of the `Tag` property of the controls in the designer, setting all 25's tag to the same string value.

Then when your form is loading:

```
foreach(var control in Controls.Where((c) => c.Tag != null && c.Tag.ToString() == "MYVALUE")
    control.Click += EventHandler;
```

In the future if you ever need to add another control, it's a simple case of setting the tag to the value you want and this code will take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign every buttons click event handler to the same method. In your designer file you will see:

```
Button1.Click += ...;
Button2.Click += ...;
```

Make them all the same.